# Recursion in F#, expected type int but got type "int list -> int"

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I'm new to F# and want to implement a least common multiple function of a list by doing it recursively, e.g. lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(a, lcm(b,c)), where lcm of two elements is calculated from the gcd.

I have the following code. I try to match the input of the lcm function with a list of two elements, and otherwise a general list, which I split up into its first element and the remaining part. The part "lcm (tail)" gives a compiler error. It says it was expected to have type "int" but has type "int list -> int". It looks like it says that the expression "lcm tail" is itself a function, which I don't understand. Why is it not an int?

```
let rec gcd a b =
    if b = 0
        then abs a
    else gcd b (a % b)

let lcmSimple a b = a*b/(gcd a b)

let rec lcm list = function
    | [a;b] -> lcmSimple a b
    | head::tail -> lcmSimple (head) (lcm (tail))
```

Best regards.

Comment: perhaps, you mean just `let rec lcm = function`

Comment: but still take a notice to warning - you don't process all from possible cases.

Comment: @FoggyFinder you are right, it works if I remove "list", but usually you include an argument to your function. I realize I never use "list", and maybe it's a matching thing. Also, I have included the empty case.

Comment: `let rec lcm list = function | ...` is shorthand for `let rec lcm list x = match x with | ...` so your function takes 2 arguments, not 1.

Comment: So, someone have to write answer. @HowDoICSharply do you want to do it?

Comment: @Lee , so "lcm tail" become a function, because I only fix the first entry of a two-variable function. Thanks both.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, yeah, I can give it a go.

Comment: btw, since you are novice in F# I advise you to join to the [FSSF slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). If you will have any problem with it - just ping me in the [SO chat F# room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f). Well, SO room is great place too, but much less active so you may have problem with getting quick answers.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, I will definitely have a look.

Answer (score 6):

When defining the function as `let f = function | ...`, the argument to the function is implicit, as it is interpreted as let `f x = match x with | ...`.

Thus `let rec lcm list = function |...` is a function of two variables, which are `list` and the implicit variable. This is why the compiler claims that `lcm tail` is a function - only one variable has been passed, where it expected two. A better version of the code is

```
let rec gcd a b =
    if b = 0
        then abs a
    else gcd b (a % b)

let lcmSimple a b = a*b/(gcd a b)

let rec lcm = function
    | [a;b] -> lcmSimple a b
    | head::tail -> lcmSimple (head) (lcm (tail))
    | [] -> 1
```

where the last case has been included to complete the pattern.